# GCC some data outside sections

Tags: c, gcc, cortex-m

This is my linker file memory definition (Cortex M4 MCU with flash memory starting at `0x0` address):

```
MEMORY
{
    m_interrupts          (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x0000A000, LENGTH = 0x00000410
    m_text                (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x0000A410, LENGTH = 0x00050BF0
    m_data                (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x1FFF0000, LENGTH = 0x0001F000
    m_data_2              (RW)  : ORIGIN = 0x2000F000, LENGTH = 0x00001000
}
```

I want to offset my flash from `0x0` to `0xA000` to keep the beginning of the flash clean.

However, when I generate my output (bin) file for my project, I can see the beginning of the flash is still occupied by some data. From `.map` file I think this is `.ARM.attributes`, `.debug_info`, `.debug_abbrev`, etc. I don't know what it is, but I want the beginning of my flash to be clean, not programmed by anything. How to remove these data from my output bin file or how to move this data to the end of the output bin file?

Comment: Don't use `.bin` files--use `.hex`, they support disjoint memory ranges.

Comment: But still I need the hex file to not contain any data in flash on address 0x0000 - 0x7FFF. How to remove the data from 0x0000 - 0x7FFF?

Comment: the vector table is at 0x00000000 you have to have that there, you can use .space or whatever to leave a gap to 0xa000 if desired.

Comment: or add a separate entry in the linker for the vector table from the handlers.

Comment: No, I need my vector table at 0xA000. I really need 0x0000 - 0x9FFF empty for my app. There is a bootloader on 0x0000 - 0x9FFF.